# logstash apache2 not getting converted to json

Tags: json, apache, logstash

A simple logstash example is not working for me. I want to read my apache access.log and dump it out. I use the following configuration file

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    grok {         
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}
output {
    stdout {}
}
```

and I cannot get json output from logstash as shown here.

root@rick-VirtualBox:/opt/logstash# ./bin/logstash -f /home/rick/log_conf/first-pipeline.conf
Logstash startup completed
2015-08-10T18:58:07.660Z rick-VirtualBox 192.168.56.1 - - [10/Aug/2015:12:46:21 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 427 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.6 Safari/600.6.3"

When i use the grokdebugger on the line above it says its a COMBINEDAPACHELOG pattern, which i believe is what i am asking for.

Isn't logStash suppose to create json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually *json* is not the default codec. According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-stdout.html) Logstash's default output codec for stdout is *line*.

Try:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

You might also consider using `codec => rubydebug` which also produces a very clean output.

Comment: that did it. I changed it to the rubydebug statement. Thanx!